# Find common words in two columns of pandas dataframe consist of list of words

Tags: python, pandas, cpu-word

I have a large pandas dataframe in python (about 1 Million rows) that has 2 columns consist of list of words (Norm1 and Norm2).

I want to create a column (common) out of the words that they have in common.

```
| Norm1               | Norm2            |
| ------------------- | -----------------|
| ['apple','inc']     | ['apple']        |
| ['apple','inc']     | ['amazon']       |
| ['apple','inc']     | ['apple','inc']  |
| ['apple','inc']     | ['Tesla']        |
```

Expected column will be:

```
|Common         |
|---------------|
|['apple']      |
|[]             |
|['apple','inc']|
|[]             |
```

Also, since the data is big, I want to do it in an efficient way.
I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Expected column is "common" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['Common'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['Norm1']).intersection(set(x['Norm2']))), axis=1)
```

This creates a set of the values in each column then finds the intersection.

I copied your example input and created a dataframe that was 1.5 million rows in length and it only took about 25 seconds to run.

Comment: Thank you! Intersection method was great. Appreciate your help

Comment: To be honest, I found the same solution (different syntax though) but on my computer it takes about 55 seconds (11 times longer than you claim). Tested with this:
`
start = time.time()
df["result"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['norm1'])&set(x['norm2'])), axis=1)
# df['Common'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['norm1']).intersection(set(x['norm2']))), axis=1)
print(time.time()-start)
`
Both statements take about 55 seconds, how did you get 5 seconds with 1.5 mln rows? (`lib = [["apple"], ["amazon"], ["apple","inc"], ["Tesla"]]*375000 
data = {"norm1": lia, "norm2": lib}`)

Comment: @JarroVGIT woops my typo mistake! On 1.5 million rows it takes about 25 seconds in a jupyter notebook, with this code: `df = pd.DataFrame({"Norm1": [["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"]],
        "Norm2": [["apple"], ["amazon"], ["apple","inc"], ["Tesla"]]})
df2 = pd.concat([df]*375000, ignore_index=True)
%timeit df2.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['Norm1']).intersection(set(x['Norm2']))), axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too but even 25 seconds is good enough for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I love these kind of questions, took me quite a while to figure out the answer (while the question is quite understandable). My code is this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Norma": [["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"], ["apple","inc"]], "Normb": [["apple"], ["amazon"], ["apple","inc"], ["Tesla"]]}

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df["result"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['Norma'])&set(x['Normb'])), axis=1)
```

The `result` Series contains the list you are looking for:

```
          Norma         Normb        result
0  [apple, inc]       [apple]       [apple]
1  [apple, inc]      [amazon]            []
2  [apple, inc]  [apple, inc]  [apple, inc]
3  [apple, inc]       [Tesla]            []
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.